# Installing locally with NPM and filesystem restrictions

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a NodeJS project.

`/home/projects/myproject/`

From inside of myproject, I have installed a bunch of npm modules locally.  I see these in

`/home/projects/myproject/node_modules`

Now I want to copy myproject to a different place on the filesystem.

`/home/otherprojects/myproject`

Will this create any problems for the locally installed npm modules?  IOW would it be safer to install all of my npm modules globally?  (I am unclear if installing them locally in any way ties them to that particular path)

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your packages are up-to-date in `package.json`.  If you copy over the entire `node_modules` folder as well then it should be fine, but what you really want is for the `package.json` to correctly list the dependencies so you can use `npm install` anywhere (even on other/different kinds of systems).

If you don't have a `package.json` yet or its dependencies aren't up-to-date, you can run `npm init` to have it generate a `package.json` with dependencies in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this shouldn't be an issue.

I've had problems moving dirs into separate disk partitions (I'm still not sure why), but deleting the `node_modules` dir and running `npm install` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, It's won't be a problem unless you're moving to different machine or partitions especially they are running on different operating system because some module are binary executable and they need to recompile again. So, if you faced such problem, you need to delete entire node_module folder and npm install again.